# Can connect to WCF from certain windows users and not from others

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

We currently use a solution with WCF web services with Windows Identity Foundation for security.
It works fine for three years now, but it seems we have certain users (I mean windows users) which cannot connect to WCF.

From the same machine with four different Users, Two can connect to the application and two cannot.

Everybody see the server part (the first call was a wsHttpBinding call to check if server exist, if failed a message is provided else we display the login window) but it failed with services with Authentication(ws2007FederationHttpBinding). It seems to be a problem from Windows User...

Has anybody already encounter this type of problem? Any idea to solve it?
We do not have physically access to the machine (client machine) and cannot make some debug to see where it comes from.

the returned exception is:

```
Could not start session - Exception: SOAP security negotiation with "My service complete address"
for target "My service complete address" failed.
```